# Show that there is $C$ s.t. $\|v\|_{L^2}\leq C\|\nabla v\|_{L^2}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H=\{v\in H^1(B_2\backslash B_2)\mid v|_{\partial B_2}=0\}$. Show that there is a constant $C>0$ s.t. for all $v\in H$, $$\|v\|_{L^2(B_2\backslash B_1)}\leq C\|\nabla v\|_{L^2(B_2\backslash B_1)}.$$

**Attempts**

Suppose it's not true. Then, there are $v_n$ s.t. $$\|v_n\|=1,\quad \|\nabla v_n\|\to 0\quad \text{and}\quad v_n|_{\partial B_2}=0.$$

Using Rellich-Kondrachov, since $v_n$ is bounded, there is a subsequence (still denoted $v_n$) s.t. $v_n\longrightarrow v$ strongly in $L^2$ and $\nabla v_n\rightharpoonup \nabla v$ weakly in $L^2$. Since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, $\nabla v_n\rightharpoonup \nabla v$ and $\|\nabla v_n\|\longrightarrow \|\nabla v\|=0$ we have that $\nabla v_n\longrightarrow \nabla v$ strongly in $L^2$.

**Q1) How can I be sure that if $\|\nabla v_n\|\to 0$ then $\|\nabla v\|=0$ ? Is there a continuity argument ? I have problem to prove it rigorously.**

Since $\|\nabla v\|=0$, we have that $\nabla v=0$ a.e. and thus $v$ is constant a.e. Since $\|v_n\|=1$ and that $v_n\longrightarrow v$ strongly, we have $\|v\|=1$.

**Q2) I have problem to get a contradiction from here. I guess that I have to use the condition $v_n|_{\partial B_2}\longrightarrow v|_{B_2}$ strongly, but since $\partial B_2$ has measure $0$ in $B_2\backslash B_1$, I have problem to use it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1 use the lower semicontinuity of the $L^2$ norm with respect to weak convergence, i.e. that 
$$
\| \nabla v\|_{L^2} \leq \liminf \| \nabla v_k\|_{L^2}.
$$

To see this write
$$
\| \nabla v\|_{L^2}^2 =(\nabla v,\nabla v)_{L^2} = \liminf (\nabla v_k,\nabla v)_{L^2}\leq \liminf \|\nabla v_k\|_{L^2} \|\nabla v\|_{L^2}.
$$

For Q2 you have to use that the trace operator $T:H^1(B_2\setminus B_1) \to L^2(\partial B_2)$ is bounded and linear. In particular it sends weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent ones (in fact it's compact so that it sends weakly convergent sequences to strongly convergent ones, but this is a little more difficult to prove). Then since $v_k\to c$ weakly in $H^1$  where $c=|B_2\setminus B_1|^{-1/2}\neq 0$ (this is what all we've done before amounts to), we must have $v=c$ on $\partial B_2$. On the other hand by assumtion $v_k=0$ on $\partial B_2$ so that, by weak convergence again we must have $v=0$ on $\partial B_2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @MathBeginner: Not necessarily. For instance any orthonormal basis $(v_k)$ of $H^1$ converges weakly to 0. By Rellich $v_k\to 0$ in $L^2$ and so $\| \nabla v_k\|_{L^2}\to 1$, but $\nabla v=\nabla 0=0$.

Comment: In fact, I have several question. **1)** if $\|\nabla v_k\|_{L^2}\to 1$, then we won't have $\|\nabla v\|=1$ right ? **2)** Why $v_k\rightharpoonup 1$ weakly ? We just have that $\|v_k\|=1$, and I don't think that it imply the weak convergence of $v_k$ to $1$, does it ? **3)** If it does, why this implies that $v=1$ on $\partial B_2$ ? Sorry, I'm not very good with those things.

Comment: @MathBeginner: 1) is above. 2) You're absolutely correct. We do tend to a constant, but this is not necessarily one. I've edited the answer. Thanks. 3) This is a property of the trace operator: For Sobolev functions with continuous representatives the trace agrees with the usual notion of restriction (see, for instance, Evans' PDE book for a precise statement).

Comment: **1)** How do you get $c=|B_2\backslash B_1|^{-1/2}$ ?  **2)** Is the trace continuous or only weakly continuous  $H^{1}(\Omega )\to H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )$ ?

Comment: @MathBeginner: from weak convergence $|\|v_n\|-c|\Omega ||^2\leq \int |v_n-v|^2\to 0$. For **2)** you have that $\|v\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega )}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega )}$, therefore the trace is continuous.

Comment: @Surb: Thanks but I don't understand why $v|_{\partial B_2}$ must be $c$. Indeed, we just know that $v=c$ a.e. so it can't be $0$ on the boundary since the measure of the boundary is $0$, no ?

Comment: @MathBeginner : Indeed, $v=c$ a.e. but if you consider $g:x\longmapsto c$, then $v_n\to g$ in $L^2$ and thus $Tr(v_n)\to Tr(g)=c$ what contradict $Tr(v_n)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @MathBeginner: It has to be that constant because it has to have $L^2$ norm 1 by the strong convergence.